# Are rank-3 tensors used as optimization objective functions?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, tensors, quadratic-programming, tensor-rank

There many optimization problems, like quadratic programming (convex optimization), that use a **matrix** within the objective function. This is a reference request for any well-known applications where **rank-3 tensors** are similarly used within the objective function of some optimization model.

Comment: The 2nd and 4rd links from googling tensor optimization . https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/705/kannanslides.pdf and https://www.math.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/dls/posters/UCLA_Lecture_3_Final.compressed.pdf

Comment: thanks, these were very technical. hope to find practical applications instead